# Dell Studio 1737 Overheating

Tags: 12.04, laptop, dell, overheating

I am using a Dell Studio 1737 laptop. I have been running Linux and have ran Windows recently for a very long time. I upgraded to the 10.10 distribution and since that distro, it seems that for some reason all Linuxes want to push my laptop to extremes. I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 since I heart that it contains kernel fixes for overheating issues. 12.04 will actually eventually cool the system, but that is after the fans run to the point it sounds like a jet aircraft taking off and the laptop makes my hands sweat.

In trying to combat the heat problems I have done the following:
I installed the propriatery driver for my ATI Mobility HD 3600. I have tried both the one in the Additional Drivers and also tried ATI's latest greatest version. If I don't install this my laptop will overheat and shut off in minutes. Both seem to perform similarly, but the heat problem remains.

I have tried limiting the CPU by installing the CPUFreq Indicator. This does help keep the machine from shutting off, but the heat is still uncomfortable to be around the machine. I usually run in power saver mode or run the cpu at 1.6 GHZ just to error on safety.

I ran sensors-detect and here are the results:

```
sean@sean-Studio-1737:~$ sudo sensors-detect # sensors-detect revision 5984 (2011-07-10 21:22:53 +0200) # System: Dell Inc. Studio 1737 (laptop) # Board: Dell Inc. 0F237N

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions, unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
     (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found `ITE IT8512E/F/G Super IO'
     (but not activated)

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel ICH9 Module i2c-i801 loaded successfully.
Module i2c-dev loaded successfully.

Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue:

Driver `coretemp':
   * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are loaded. You may want to run 'service module-init-tools start'
to load them.

Unloading i2c-dev... OK
Unloading i2c-i801... OK
Unloading cpuid... OK

sean@sean-Studio-1737:~$ sudo service module-init-tools start module-init-tools stop/waiting
```

I also tried installing i8k but that didn't work since it didn't seem to be able to communicate with the hardware (probably for different kind of device).

Also I ran acpi -V and here are the results:

```
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 613 mAh, last full capacity 260 mAh = 42% Adapter 0: on-line Thermal 0: ok, 49.0 degrees C Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 100.0 degrees C Thermal 1: ok, 48.0 degrees C Thermal 1: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 100.0 degrees C Thermal 2: ok, 51.0 degrees C Thermal 2: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 100.0 degrees C Cooling 0: LCD 0 of 15 Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 10 Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
```

I have hit a wall and don't know what to do now. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: No need to edit and add "solved", instead mark the answer you like as completed when you can.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was resolved by doing the following:

1. Fresh install of 12.04
2. Update Ubuntu - sudo apt-get update && sudo
   apt-get upgrade from command line Install All Drivers (I installed
   ATI's driver from their site)
3. Install lm-sensors
4. Install cpufreq indicator
5. Set cpufreq indicator to “On Demand” Run sensors-detect (yes to everything)
6. Installed acpi and fancontrol
7. Reboot - At this point the sensors command showed that my computer was cool
   (40c-45c) but the fans ran constantly and the computer was still way
   too hot to touch.
8. Take a can of air to the fans – this was the last thing I did and it actually fixed the problem, even though Windows 7 never ran the fans up. When I blow out the fans the overheating stopped.

Thus the problem was solved.

Comment: @papashou that is not how things work here, you mark the "Answer" as Accepted, It is a green check-box next to the Up/Down Vote on the Answer.